# Passing a variable to another php page

Tags: php

From comprobar.php

marcarpagado.php gets NULL, why?

```
echo '<a href="marcarpagado.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Marcar como pagado</a>';
```

In marcarpagado.php:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: what do you see in the source though?  is there an actual value for id?  i think you'll find $id isn't echoing out the way you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `echo` two times.

It should be like this

```
echo "<a href='marcarpagado.php?id=".$id."'>Marcar como pagado</a>";
```

Comment: Single quotes dont allow the variable to be echoed

Comment: Why not a function like sprintf?

Answer (score 0):

You are using php tag again inside php and `echo` inside `echo` .so

change

```
  echo '<a href="marcarpagado.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Marcar como pagado</a>';
```

to

```
echo "<a href='marcarpagado.php?id=$id'>Marcar como pagado</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**invalid format php tag in echo statement**

```
      echo '<a href="marcarpagado.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Marcar como pagado</a>';
```

replace it with

```
echo "<a href='marcarpagado.php?id=$id'>Marcar como pagado</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing your PHP

ie:

```
echo '<a href="marcarpagado.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Marcar como pagado</a>';
```

within this string you another set of php tags, 
the string should read

```
echo '<a href="marcarpagado.php?id='.$id.'">Marcar como pagado</a>';
```

have a look here for string operators 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: There is no need for echo when using the dot append operator

Comment: hehe, copy and paste! forgot to remove the echo.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo '<a href="marcarpagado.php?id='.$id.'">Marcar como pagado</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to : `echo '<a href="marcarpagado.php?id='. $id .'">Marcar como pagado</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like [sprintf](https://www.php.net/sprintf) :

```
echo sprintf('<a href="marcarpagado.php?id=%d">Marcar como pagado</a>',$id);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Nested echo is not supported in php.